# How to clean up duplicate data from my MySQL database, using certain implicit keys?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following rows in my database:

```
ID    FirstName    LastName    Telephone    Gender    Address
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1     John         Smith       211          null      SomeAddress
2     John         Smith       211          Male      null
3     John         Smith       211          null      null
```

I have decided that these records are duplicates, because I want only one row to have the same `FirstName`, `LastName` and `Telephone`. So, I want to delete the duplicate rows, but still keep the not-null values for `Gender` and `Address`. Thus, my final, merged record would be:

```
ID    FirstName    LastName    Telephone    Gender    Address
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1     John         Smith       211          Male      SomeAddress
```

My primary key is ID, but I don't think that matters.

Is there any clever way to do that using SQL?

Comment: You can use `SELECT MAX(Gender), MAX(Address) FROM yourtable GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Telephone`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's only one possible value under `Gender` and `Address` , I suggest creating a new table which will be easier :

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (firstname,lastname,telephone,gender,address)
SELECT t.firstName,t.lastName,t.telephone,MAX(t.gender) as gender,MAX(t.address) as address
FROM OldTable t
GROUP BY t.firstName,t.lastName,t.telephone
```

Make `ID` auto increment so it generates it again.

Comment: You don't need the aliases in your select.

Comment: I always alias, regardless if I need it or not. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with identical columns to your current table.  Then do the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO newTable(FirstName, LastName, Telephone, Gender, Address)
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Telephone, MAX(Gender), MAX(Address)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    FirstName, LastName, Telephone
```

Then, delete the original table.

Comment: `ID` shouldn't be specified in your select , it is unique.